# Does A Rapid Drop In Blood Sugar Correspond With A Rapid Drop Of Insulin?

Tags: nutrition, blood-sugar, insulin

I've done some research on the internet about blood sugar and insulin.

It's mentioned that drinking something like a cup of soda (basically sugar water) can cause a rapid spike of blood sugar and insulin but then a rapid drop in blood sugar (headaches, feeling sleepy/tired, etc.) (https://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2011/03/21/watch-how-soda-affects-your-body.aspx)

Does this rapid drop apply to insulin too?

Comment: It would be better if you gave reference to the site from which your research was based. Plus the topic of your question is completely different from your original question.

Comment: @Prince just added a reference. Sorry about that :)